# How to remove brackets and quotation marks from array Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the below class method:

```
def self.product(basket)
  Product.find(basket.to_a).collect do |product| 
    product.name + " " + product.size + " " + product.color
  end
end
```

The above produces the following:

```
["T-Shirt Medium Grey", "Sweatshirt Medium Black"]
```

I've tried the following:

```
def self.product(basket)
  a = Product.find(basket.to_a).collect do |product| 
    product.name + " " + product.size + " " + product.color
  end
  b = a.shift.strip
end
```

But this ends up only giving me the first part of the array `T-shirt Medium Grey`

I'm looking for it to give me

```
T-shirt Medium Grey, Sweatshirt Medium Black
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What is the output you are looking for?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your problem is how to customize displaying array content. One of possible solution is converting to string using [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-join) method:

```
a.join(', ')
# => "T-Shirt Medium Grey, Sweatshirt Medium Black"
```

Comment: bravoooooooooooo!

Comment: again bravoooo! hehe

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
def self.product(basket)
  Product.find(basket.to_a).map{|product| [product.name, product.size, product.color].join(" ")}.join(', ')
end
```